# Python NoneType object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Iam building a UI using mplayer_python.

When I try to get the metadata, sometimes the following error happens

```
title = metadata.get ('Title','' )
```

-> AttributeError: 'NoneType' has no attribute 'get'

is there any way to check if the operation is valid

like

```
if SOMETHING : title = metadata.get ('Title','' )
```

??

Iam new to python so any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that `metadata` is `None`. You can use `if metadata`.